# Mobile Menu wont center on Astra WordPress Theme.. Please advise?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, mobile-website

I have tried created a landing page using the free version of Astra for WordPress. I'm very happy with the design apart from what happens to the menu on mobile view.

In the Astra options, the mobile menu should center; the logo, the CTA and the hamburger icon. As you can see from the attached image, it is slightly off to the right.

I have also tried using CSS to select the element and use text-align: center.

Nothing seems to work...please help?

Image is below and the URL is: DOMAIN REMOVED

[1]: IMAGE REMOVED

Comment: Maybe there is some left-over or white space on the right side of the image?

Comment: Even without the logo, the same issue occurs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a:

```
.ast-logo-title-inline .site-logo-img {
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

in your css. Remove this.

Or set:

```
.site-logo-img {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

in your child themes style.css

Edit:

```
.ast-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Regards Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the suggestion. I have removed the above from both the minified and un-minified version and it still appears the same? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I think the code you provided is affecting the logo and not the two buttons which are the issue.

Comment: I updated my answer. That .ast-container has a padding left and right. I thought the problem was that the logo is off-center above those buttons.

Comment: Perfect tom! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You should install a child theme and make the changes there. If you change the astra theme itself then any update will override the changes.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.